# Multidrop system using DS18B20

Tags: sensor, temperature

As per the datasheet, to use Multidrop system, I have to match for the ROM address of the slave device, and then issue the READ ROM [0x33]command.

But as per my understanding its a static process, i.e. having all the slaves connected on board we cannot obtain the address of a single slave. Each have to be connected separately, obtain the address and so on.

Is there any method to get the sensor value without knowing the address, in multidrop system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct. The datasheet specifically explains that READ ROM command can only be used with a single device on bus. But with a single device on bus, you don't even have to use the ROM address.

When there are multiple devices on bus, you must go through the identification process to figure out which ROM IDs there are on the bus, and then each time you want to command a single sensor, it must be selected by sending the ROM address first and then only the selected sensor will listen for the next command.

The ROM ID search procedure is well defined, and even the datasheet points to the application note how to scan the bus for IDs.